# R - barplot that displays sums of values of 2 y colums grouped by different variables

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to create a barplot with `R`displaying the sums of `2 columns` of data grouped by a variable. the data is set up like this:

```
"city" "n" "y" <br>
mon 100 200 <br>
tor 209 300 <br>
edm 98 87 <br>
mon 20 76 <br>
tor 50 96 <br>
edm 62 27 <br>
```

the resulting plot should have city as the `x-axis`, 2 bars per city, 1 representing the sum of `"n`" in that city, the other the sum of `"y"` in that city.

*If possible also show the sum in each bar as a label?*

I have tried the following:

```
d <- melt(data[,c('City','n','y')],id.vars = 1)

plot <- ggplot(d,aes(x = City,y = value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

This generates a plot in the desired format, but the values are not sums of the groups.

I tried aggregating the data into sums like this:

```
sum_data <- aggregate(. ~ City,data=raw_data,sum)
```

this gave me the sums per city as I wanted but for some reason 1 of the cities is missing in the output.

Using this code for the plot:

```
ggplot(sum_data,aes(x = City,y = n)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = y),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

gave be a bar plot with one bar per city showing the sum of y as a color gradient. not what I expected given the "dodge" command in geom_bar.

Thanks.

Comment: This site is not to make homework for you. Let us see some code that you tried yourself and ask us a well defined question about the things that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work this way:

import the data with readr, taking in only the columns that have numeric values ("n" and "y") and the column with the groups ("city").

aggregate the data by the group ("City") so that each variable has a sum:

```
sum_data <- aggregate(.~City__c,data=raw_data,sum)
```

reshape the data so that the groups are now variables (there will be 3 columns: "City", "variable", "value"):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
sums <- melt(sum_data)
```

plot using ggplot:

```
ggplot(sums, aes(x = City, y= value, fill = variable, ymax = 1000)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.8, position = "dodge")
```